# Reduced Chebyshev approximation?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, approximation, chebyshev-polynomials

Few days ago my teacher mentioned a method of approximation for a function. I think it was called "reduced chebyshev approximation", where you find the taylor series of degree $N$ then subtract from it the chebychev polynomials of degree $N-1$. Does anyone know what my teacher was talking about? I have been looking online  for days to find this kind of approximation but couldn't find any.

Comment: It's Chebyshev but I assume you figured that out?! Is your question about how to perform what you say or is it about ffinding references, I don't think "reduced Chebyshev approximation" is a common term but the approximation by Taylor series and by Chebyshev polynomials has been compared,as an example [https://www.google.ch/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=6&ved=0ahUKEwiLxrXwqYHNAhUJVRQKHW0TC24QFgg9MAU&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.ams.org%2Fmcom%2F1988-50-181%2FS0025-5718-1988-0917828-4%2FS0025-5718-1988-0917828-4.pdf&usg=AFQjCNF_5GodiOr1DSksDOPYxmnwHWR11Q&sig2=4nHn-Q1ZMpKdaioPuP7UNg].

Comment: I think you may be referring to "economization of power series".  Google that phrase and you will find many hits.